# Cohen-Macaulayness of the scheme of centralizer

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, schemes

Let $G$ be a simply connected group over an algebraically closed field $k$, and

$I:=\{(g,\gamma)\in G\times G\vert~ g\gamma=\gamma g\}$

the scheme of centralizer.

Is $I$ a Cohen-Macaulay scheme over $k$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is not known. In fact, the analogous result for the "commuting variety" $\mathcal{C}(\mathfrak{g})$ of a reductive Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ ($\mathcal{C}(\mathfrak{g})=\{(x,y)\in \mathfrak{g}\times \mathfrak{g}\ |\ [x,y]=0\}$) is a classical conjecture -- even the normality of $\mathcal{C}(\mathfrak{g})$ is not known. See V. Popov, 
*[Irregular and singular loci of commuting varieties](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00031-008-9018-9)*. 
Transform. Groups 13 (2008), no. 3-4, 819–837 ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2452617)).

Comment: A fairly recent arXiv paper of Charbonnel claims to prove Cohen-Macaulayness for ${\mathcal C}({\mathfrak g})$ - see Thm. 4.3(iii) in arxiv.org/abs/1206.5592. I guess Charbonnel's paper must be under review.

Comment: @PaulLevy, there is a recent [J. Algebra paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869316300345) with a similar title.  However, unlike the [arXiv paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5592) you linked, it has a co-author, and at least the introduction is completely different, so who knows what happened.

Comment: I think that is not directly related - it is http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0377, which appeared before 1206.5592.